# How to set a property if the value is in another thread

Tags: c#

I want set a property where the value is in another thread

```
[DllExport]
public static bool Value()
{
    bool val = false;
    Thread thread = new Thread(async () => val = await getVal());
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    return val;
}

public async Task<bool> getVal()
{
    bool value = false;
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        string rs = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
        if (rs == "1")
            value = true;
        else
            value = false;
    });
    return value;

}
```

It always returns `false` why I use that one is I cant use await in a static [DLLExport] method otherwise the form will freeze.

Edit: I cant use async in a DllExport method

Comment: What is `getVal()`? Can you prepare [mcve] and we will try to see what to do with freezing or always `false`.

Comment: You don't need a thread at all. What does `getVal()` do? If it returns a `Task`, it's most likely already running in the background.

Comment: BTW what's the point of that `Value()` method in the first place? Once the unwanted thread is removed it's no different than `bool Value(){ getVal(); return false;}`. Even the original code doesn't wait for anything to complete before returning `false`. You should probably change any code that calls `Value()` to `var val=await getValue();`

Comment: @MongZhu No, you cant make a [DLLExport] static method not async

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the problem is I cant use async in that method

Comment: it seems that you have an async method which you would like to call synchronously. are you basically trying to write a synchronous wrapper for that thing (`getVal()`)?

Comment: The short answer - remove all your use of `Task` and `Thread`. Make it synchronous. _It can be better using `async` but that is a larger refactoring._

Comment: @mjwills yes I also tried that but the windows form is freezing for some secounds

Comment: OK - my suggestion is this. a) Stop using `Thread`. b) Use `HttpClient` rather than `WebClient`. c) Look for `Async` ways to return data using `HttpClient`. d) Read up on `async await`.

Comment: @mjwills but that is the same then I need to use await but I cant use it because in a [DllExport] method is not works

Comment: Why does this need to be `DllExport`?

Comment: the function needs to be unmanaged dll exported from a application

Comment: You seem to have two competing requirements. a) It must be synchronous, since it is `DllExport`. b) It can't be synchronous, since it freezes the UI. I can't think of a way to solve that issue.

Comment: @serman0 You can use `getVal().Result` to block until the async operation completes and return the result. What your code did though was start a thread that run an async operation and nobody tried to retrieve the result

Comment: you could also run it in the background and use an event to signal the resulting value, when the background thread is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well starting the Thread really tells you nothing about when the code is being run.

After you call .Start() you tell the thread to run its code, but you have no real control of when the OS decides to actually let the code run.

Im also not sure how using locally defined variables inside the other thread-scope actually works, but I find it hard to think that you can set the value like you are trying to do.

Try googling Monitor.Wait(), Monitor.Pulse() which can be used to let one thread wait for another to finish (one calls Monitor.Wait() and the other calls Monitor.Pulse() when it wants the waiting thread to start executing).

Comment: @serman0 I'd love to see the final solution, since I am mystified how this is going to help.